# C# Registering Mouse Click Globally

Tags: c#, hook, mouse, global

I'm trying to change the text of one string when I press left mouse button. I've tried to do it several ways, using different methods I've found online, but nothing seems to work. At the moment, I'm trying to use the code I've found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mouse.leftbutton?view=netframework-4.7.2

Code of the class I've made for this looks like this:

```
class ClickMNG
{
public static MouseButtonState LeftButton { get; }

public static void ClickScan()
{

    if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {

        ClickLog.Click = "[Click]\n";

    }
  }
 }
```

String Click is in another class (ClickLog). There are no errors/warnings/exceptions, but it fails to change the text of string Click. Also, I've tried to use MouseKeyHook NuGet package(https://www.nuget.org/packages/MouseKeyHook/), and it only makes my cursor bugging when I debug my app, doesn't change my string value :p

Comment: Are you registering ClickScan as an event handler somewhere? Can you post that code?

Comment: I'm calling ClickMNG.ClickScan(); in program's Main method

Comment: Can you include your main method? Or at least the relevant part(s).

Comment: This is the only relevant part, and whole main method is kinda too big to be included. I just have ClickMNG.ClickScan(); in my Main as the only line connected with this :)

Comment: Well, if you just call it from Main, then whether this does anything or not depends on whether you happen to have the mouse button pressed when that line executes. I guess I'd recommend putting some logging in so you can be sure the method is called and what state the mouse is in when it does get called.